# Who sets the thread culture in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to internationalize my WP7 app.  I have localized resources, `SupportedCultures` tag etc.  But I'm wondering who is responsible for setting the `Thread.CurrentThread.Current*Culture`?  Is this set for me when the user changes their language on the device or do I have to detect the device language / region and set the thread culture accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property to determine the current region that has been set for the device. This is set by the framework; you do not have to set it yourself. If you need to change the locale for some reason, you can set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` properties.

You can test localized applications in the emulator by changing the region in the settings.